# Odd results for Image Recognition using AlexNet in Deep Learning

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, image-recognition

I am using a modified AlexNet (cifar-10-model) available in the tensorflow tutorials to do some image recognition of some mechanic part images but getting very wierd results.

The training accuracy is very soon to achieve 100%. But the testing accuracy is starting as high as 45% decreasing very fast to as low as 9%.

I am doing my test on a training set of 20,000 images and testing set of 2,500 images with 8 categories. I do training and testing by batch with size of 1024.

The accuracy and training loss is showed below and you can see that:

1. The testing accuracy starts at as high as 45%, which doesn't make sense.
2. The mechanical images are always classified as 'left bracket'
   [Accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUhyE.png)
   [Classification results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndQU9.jpg)

Comment: what do you mean with "batch" in testing?

Comment: Do you have a third picture about Classification Results?

Comment: I feed the model with images by batch size of 1024.:)

Comment: Thank you. I have update the pictures. I want to show the classification results.

Comment: What is the distribution of classes in the training and testing sets?  Also, when do you first test the accuracy?  Does any training take place prior to the first evaluation of test data?

Comment: @ZhenyuWu Your edit removed the embedded images, please pay attention to the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

your testing accuracy is decreasing, I think it happens because of Overfitting. Try to use simpler model or regularization method to tune the model.

Comment: I think so. But you can see that the testing accuracy starts at 45%. Since our training data has 8 categories, such a high testing accuracy doesn't make sense.:) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your data or feature extraction for errors. I did a protein structure prediction for **3-labels**, but I was using a wrong extraction method. My validation accuracy starts at 45% too and then falls quickly.

Knowing where my errors are, I started from scratch: now I do protein structure prediction for **8-labels**. The accuracy from the first epoch is 60% and able to rise steadily to 64.9% (the current Q8 world record for CB513 is 68.9%).

So validation accuracy starting at 45% is not a problem, but falling quickly is. I'm afraid that you have an error somewhere in your data/extraction rather than just overfitting.